# How to mute Monitor in Datadog, when Windows Service has status Disabled?

Tags: datadog

Is it possible to automatically mute created Datadog Monitor(which is monitoring Windows Service), when Windows service state was changed from Automatic to Disabled?
How can it be configured
Thanks.

Comment: you should be able to set up a downtime on one / all monitors over a specific tag scope, like `service_state:disabled` or something. Then when the service state is changed from automatic to disabled, as long as that tag is applied/removed correctly, then it should get muted from monitor evaluations automatically.

Comment: Where this tag should be set? I have Tag only for group of monitors..But this tag does not depend on windows service state of service..

Comment: where is the tag set on the downtime? in the "Group Scope" field ([docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/downtimes/#schedule-downtime)). where is the tag set on the windows service? I think that's already going to be applied by default, since i think you're using [the Windows Services integration](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/windows_service/)